# How can I enable google analytics tracking on Contact Form 7 when I have one or more checked checkbuttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, contact-form-7

My contact form has this Format:

```
<div class="col-md-12">[text* text-813 placeholder "Name:"]</div>
<div class="col-md-12">[email* email-597 placeholder "EMail:"]</div>
<div class="col-md-12">[tel* tel-345 placeholder "Tel:"]</div>
</p>
[checkbox checkbox-770 id:Personal use_label_element "Personal"]
[checkbox checkbox-771 id:Buisness use_label_element "My Buisness"]
</div>
[textarea textarea-552 placeholder "Ask about anything!"]</div>
[submit "Submit"]</div>
```

And I want to enable GA tracking for their respective fields when one or more of the checkbox inputs are checked.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
            dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'Form_Submission' 
            'Interest': 'Business'
            });
        } 

        if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
            dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'Form_Submission' 
            'Interest': 'Personal'
            });
        }
    });

}, false );
```

But it doesn't work, I get no errors as a result.
Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I assume you need **tag manager** for this

Comment: This code is from the Google tag manager dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'Form_Submission' 
            'Interest': 'Business'
            });.
I guess the question is how to include the value from the checkbox to the event listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `event.detail.inputs` that is passed by `wpcf7submit`

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    let inputs = event.detail.inputs;
    for ( let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( 'checkbox-770[]' == inputs[i].name ) {
            dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'Form_Submission',
                'Interest': 'Personal'
            });
        } else if ('checkbox-771[]' === inputs[i].name ){
            dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'Form_Submission',
                'Interest': 'Business'
            });
        }
    }
}, false );
```